# How is method injection implemented？

Tags: java, spring

During my implementation of spring-like dependency injection, I was puzzled by the fact that spring can injected beans by invoking internal methods, but how did it do this?

How can I implement ioc container like this:

```
@Bean
public A a() {
    return new A();
}

@Bean
public B b() {
    B b = new B();
    b.setA(a());
    return b;
}

@Bean
public C c() {
    C c = new C();
    c.setB(b());
    return c;
}
```

Comment: This only applies to `@Configuration` classes. A proxy is created for the configuration class, which proxies `@Bean` methods and dependending onthe scope the result of the method is cached and will return the same instance.

Comment: The question is that i cannot do anything when method b calls method a internally, or method c calls method b internally, in this case method a or method b is out control of proxy.

Comment: What does *"i cannot do anything"* mean?

Comment: That is for regular class proxies, however `@Configuration`  classes are processed with a combination of ASM and cglib, which allows for a more low level integration which makes this possible. It will NOT work with a regular cglib proxy (like for components).

Comment: I misunderstood something， problem was solved ，thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming we are talking about `@Configuration` class, dynamic instance proxy is created (using CGLIB) and than all methods invocations are intercepted by proxy logic.

In case of singleton beans (default bean scope) actual method will be invoked only once on first invocation - this is something you can verify yourself using the debugger. Consecuive calls are intercepted and proped instance is returned from the registry.

Comment: Thanks! I did use the cglib proxy, but how do I proxy inter-class method calls ?

Comment: As far as I know，when spring calls method b, this moment b is proxied by cglib, i can do something in the interceptor, 
but when method b calls method a internally, method a is outside the control of the proxy, i can't do anything at this moment!

Comment: @木有财 As already explained, method `a()` is only invoked **once**, no matter how many times you call it. Spring will call `a()` to register Bean named "a". Spring will then call `b()` to register Bean named "b", but when `b()` calls `a()` it gets the already returned `A` object without `a()` actually getting invoked. Same for `c()`, its call of `b()` doesn't actually invoke the `b()` method, since the `B` object is already cached.